# Why is my text wrapping only after most of it is drawn outside of the element?

Tags: html, css

This HTML has two segments, side by side.  I don't want the second segment to wrap under the first one, however I want the text in both to wrap within their segments.

Also, I'd ideally like both segments to shrink at the same time.  I understand I can use flexbox for this - so if that's my only option, fair enough, but if there's another way I'd like to learn.  This is not as important a concern to me at the moment.

More important is the wrapping.  Why does it eventually wrap but only after the containing element is ridiculously small?  If I remove the `white-space:nowrap` in the container, then the text all wraps as I'd expect - but the second segment wraps under the first one, which I don't want.

How do I have the segments side by side, but have the text in them wrap before drawing outside of the segment?

Here's the HTML/CSS:

```css
.container {
  text-align: left;
  background-color: grey;
  padding: 1rem;
  border-radius: 4px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline-block;
}

.title {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.text {
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.segment {
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: normal;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span class="segment">
    <div class="title">Timeline</div>
    <div class="text">Here's a bunch of text that is very nice and long and I wish it would start wrapping before it does.</div>
  </span>
  <span class="segment">This is also some nice text but it draws way out of the element before it starts wrapping.</span>
</div>
```

Comment: why do you need `white-space: nowrap;`?

Comment: The `white-space: nowrap` stops the righthand span (with the `segment` class) from wrapping under the lefthand span.  Remove it and you'll see what I mean.  I want those spans to remain side but side but the text in each to wrap.

Comment: then you need to set segment width, for example to 50%

Comment: Also, semantically, you should not be placing a block element like `div` within an inline element, like `span`, even if you are changing the display property.

Comment: @Lashane, thank you.  You are a wonderful person.

Comment: @chazsolo I've heard a few rules on that, none of which make any practical difference.  I was working with the rule of thumb 'divs are breaking elements, so if you are stacking them use divs, and if they are side by side use spans'. Locally to those divs, they are stacked and nothing is beside them.  Their parent element is. No one has provided me with an explanation of what difference it makes motivating enough for me to care yet.  Feel free to try ;)

Comment: Block vs. inline has more to do than just how they "stack" either vertically or inline. If you care for some reading on the real reasons, you could [read the specs](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#the-span-element). It boils down to semantics (and if you care about valid HTML, confusing other developers, etc.); if that isn't motivation enough, I'm not sure a comment debate could settle it :)

Comment: I'm happy to learn, and I have no real opinion on this other than just readapting my behaviour when I'm told I'm doing it wrong.  Honestly I read the link to the specs and it doesn't say anything meaningful to me on this topic.  What's the key I should be looking for in there?  Phrasing content vs Flow content?  Flow content's definition seems pretty vague for a 'spec'.

Comment: In this case, the **context in which the element can be used**: Phrasing Content, which if you follow the links, "...is the text of the document, as well as elements that mark up that text at the intra-paragraph level".

Comment: Yeah I read that and it makes sense, but with the definition of Flow content being so vague it is hard to directly compare the two.  I appreciate you taking the time to help educate me on this though - maybe I'll find an article discussing it in more conversational terms and learn this properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the example below. Is that the result you were going for?

The changes I made were:

- Remove `white-space: nowrap;`
- Added widths to the segments
- Changed the `spans` to `divs`

```css
.container {
  text-align: left;
  background-color: grey;
  padding: 1rem;
  border-radius: 4px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.title {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.text {
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.segment {
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: normal;
  width: 49%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="segment">
      <div class="title">Timeline</div>
      <div class="text">Here's a bunch of text that is very nice and long and I wish it would start wrapping before it does. </div>
  </div>
  <div class="segment">This is also some nice text but it draws way out of the element before it starts wrapping.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It works, although it seems all I really needed was the width in the segment class.  Any reason you have the width as 49% instead of 50%?

Comment: @WillyC i didnt want to look into the padding, but 50% in that above code example will push the right segment below the first section (probably because of padding etc).

Comment: So - I noticed now if I have an image in the second segment (just replace the text with `<img src="someimage.gif">`, the width doesn't expand to accommodate the image as it does with the text.  It gets bigger than without the image there, but not large enough to actually stop the image from drawing outside of the container.

Comment: @WillyC i apologize, im more of a visual person. would you be able to create a demo of that and then i can take a look?

Comment: I'd prefer they are both still 50%.  Granted I see how that could be done with table-cells, but why does it do this?  Why do the segments get larger when an image is there (as opposed to a very short word), but not large enough?  Shouldn't it expand to fit the content without having to use tables?